# system("cls") equivalent in D or something similar?

Tags: console, d

How do I clear the console screen in D? In C/C++ I used system("cls"). Is there something similar to it in D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `system("cls")` in D too. You just need to import the std.process module:

```
import std.process;

int main() {
  version(windows) {
    system("cls");
  } else {
    system("clear");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, I suggest avoiding the system() call ([read why](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/j3wTURfi/)). I would rather use Console API on Windows, and Curses API on platforms that support curses (ncurses and pdcurses work on Windows too).